Dataset of words that designate humans only if they are used as nouns
I'm looking for a dataset of words that designate humans only if they are used as nouns.
Examples of words that designate humans only if they are used as a nouns:

abecedarian
academic
activist

I am mostly interested in English but I am also interested in other languages.

I am still interested in such a dataset.

Any pointer is welcome.
